# Why when using the mouse with raycast it's moving the mesh to the other side?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What i want is to use the mouse to draw line over the terrain including over the heights.

I took this answer code from here:

[draw grid over terrain](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/442581/how-to-draw-a-grid-over-parts-of-the-terrain.html)

And i converted the code from java to c#
Not sure if i converted it fine i'm not getting any errors.

I added a new Camera to the Hierarchy.
Attached to the camera the components: Mesh Filter, Mesh Renderer, Line Renderer.
And also attached the script to the Camera.

When i move the mouse around the mesh is moving to the other directions. It's not moving with the mouse cursor.

But my main goal is to use the GetHeightmapPosition() method with the line renderer or maybe with the mesh so when i move the mouse it will draw a line with curves according to the mouse cursor position/s.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class DrawMouse : MonoBehaviour
{
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Terrain Data

    public Terrain terrain;
    private TerrainData terrainData;
    private Vector3 terrainSize;
    private int heightmapWidth;
    private int heightmapHeight;
    private float[,] heightmapData;


    void GetTerrainData()
    {
        if (!terrain)
        {
            terrain = Terrain.activeTerrain;
        }

        terrainData = terrain.terrainData;

        terrainSize = terrain.terrainData.size;

        heightmapWidth = terrain.terrainData.heightmapWidth;
        heightmapHeight = terrain.terrainData.heightmapHeight;

        heightmapData = terrainData.GetHeights(0, 0, heightmapWidth, heightmapHeight);
    }


    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Raycast To Terrain

    private Vector3 rayHitPoint;
    private Vector3 heightmapPos;

    void Start()
    {
        GetTerrainData();
        ConstructMesh();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // raycast to the terrain
        RaycastToTerrain();

        // find the heightmap position of that hit
        GetHeightmapPosition();

        // Calculate Grid
        CalculateGrid();

        // Update Mesh
        UpdateMesh();
    }


    void RaycastToTerrain()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray rayPos = GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(rayPos, out hit, Mathf.Infinity)) // also consider a layermask to just the terrain layer
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(GetComponent<Camera>().transform.position, hit.point, Color.red);
            rayHitPoint = hit.point;
        }
    }


    void GetHeightmapPosition()
    {
        // find the heightmap position of that hit
        heightmapPos.x = (rayHitPoint.x / terrainSize.x) * float.Parse(heightmapWidth.ToString());
        heightmapPos.z = (rayHitPoint.z / terrainSize.z) * float.Parse(heightmapHeight.ToString());

        // convert to integer
        heightmapPos.x = Mathf.Round(heightmapPos.x);
        heightmapPos.z = Mathf.Round(heightmapPos.z);

        // clamp to heightmap dimensions to avoid errors
        heightmapPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(heightmapPos.x, 0, heightmapWidth - 1);
        heightmapPos.z = Mathf.Clamp(heightmapPos.z, 0, heightmapHeight - 1);
    }


    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Calculate Grid

    private Vector3[,] mapGrid = new Vector3[9, 9];

    public float indicatorSize = 1.0f;
    public float indicatorOffsetY = 5.0f;


    void CalculateGrid()
    {
        for (int z = -4; z < 5; z++)
        {
            for (int x = -4; x < 5; x++)
            {
                Vector3 calcVector;

                calcVector.x = heightmapPos.x + (x * indicatorSize);
                calcVector.x /= float.Parse(heightmapWidth.ToString());
                calcVector.x *= terrainSize.x;

                float calcPosX = heightmapPos.x + (x * indicatorSize);
                calcPosX = Mathf.Clamp(calcPosX, 0, heightmapWidth - 1);

                float calcPosZ = heightmapPos.z + (z * indicatorSize);
                calcPosZ = Mathf.Clamp(calcPosZ, 0, heightmapHeight - 1);

                calcVector.y = (heightmapData[(int)calcPosZ, (int)calcPosX]) * terrainSize.y; // heightmapData is Y,X ; not X,Y (reversed)
                calcVector.y += indicatorOffsetY; // raise slightly above terrain

                calcVector.z = heightmapPos.z + (z * indicatorSize);
                calcVector.z /= float.Parse(heightmapHeight.ToString());
                calcVector.z *= terrainSize.z;

                mapGrid[x + 4, z + 4] = calcVector;
            }
        }
    }


    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------- INDICATOR MESH

    private Mesh mesh;

    private Vector3[] verts;
    private Vector2[] uvs;
    private int[] tris;


    void ConstructMesh()
    {
        if (!mesh)
        {
            mesh = new Mesh();
            GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
            mesh.name = gameObject.name + "Mesh";
        }

        mesh.Clear();

        verts = new Vector3[9 * 9];
        uvs = new Vector2[9 * 9];
        tris = new int[8 * 2 * 8 * 3];

        float uvStep = 1.0f / 8.0f;

        int index = 0;
        int triIndex = 0;

        for (int z = 0; z < 9; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            {
                verts[index] = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
                uvs[index] = new Vector2(float.Parse(x.ToString()) * uvStep, float.Parse(z.ToString()) * uvStep);

                if (x < 8 && z < 8)
                {
                    tris[triIndex + 0] = index + 0;
                    tris[triIndex + 1] = index + 9;
                    tris[triIndex + 2] = index + 1;

                    tris[triIndex + 3] = index + 1;
                    tris[triIndex + 4] = index + 9;
                    tris[triIndex + 5] = index + 10;

                    triIndex += 6;
                }

                index++;
            }
        }


        // - Build Mesh -
        mesh.vertices = verts;
        mesh.uv = uvs;
        mesh.triangles = tris;

        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }


    void UpdateMesh()
    {
        int index = 0;

        for (int z = 0; z < 9; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            {
                verts[index] = mapGrid[x, z];

                index++;
            }
        }

        // assign to mesh
        mesh.vertices = verts;

        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }
}
```